# How do I stream a bitmap using WCF and the net.tcp binding?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to pass a bitmap from a client to server using wcf and net.tcp binding.

Here's my code so far... please suggest what would be the best way to make it stream that bitmap?

```
    public void ScreenShot()
    {
          ...

        System.Drawing.Bitmap gdiBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

        apc.server.return_screenshot(name, gdiBitmap);
        ///The socket connection was aborted.
        ///This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout 
        ///being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. 
        ///Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9700000'.
    }
```

...

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "server",
    CallbackContract = typeof(IfaceServer2Client),
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]


    public interface IfaceClient2Server           ///// what comes from the client to the server.
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void StartConnection(string clientName);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Message_Cleint2Server(string msg);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void ret_listDrives(string n, List<TreeNode> nodeList);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void return_screenshot(string n, Bitmap img); /// <- here I'm trying to pass the bitmap.
    }


    public interface IfaceServer2Client          ///// what goes from the sertver, to the client.
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void AcceptConnection();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void RejectConnection();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Message_Server2Client(string msg);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void cmd_listDrives();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void cmd_changeName(string n);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void cmd_screenshot();
    }
```

Thanks!

edit:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        duplex = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerClass));

        NetTcpBinding tcp = new NetTcpBinding();

        duplex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IfaceClient2Server), tcp, "net.tcp://localhost:9080/service");

        duplex.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try serializing the bitmap to a memory stream and hand it over as a byte array ...

//edit

example: Bitmap -> byte[] -> Bitmap

```
//lets get a dummy bitmap ... 
Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap(Width,Height);
//... and paint the current form 
this.DrawToBitmap(bmp,new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height));

//we want to get a byte[] representation ... a MemoryStreams buffer will do
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
//save image to stream ... the stream will write it into the buffer
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

//get the buffer 
byte[] bitmapBytes = ms.GetBuffer();

//now you can transfer this byte array ...

//on the receiver end you want to get your bitmap back...
//create a new memorystream around the byte array
ms = new MemoryStream(bitmapBytes);
//read the Bitmap back
bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
//use it ...
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: I'm kinda new to this stuff... could you please explain it in more details? :)

Comment: Thanks! Hmm... but it still shows the same error, when I'm trying to pass the byte[] bmpBytes...             ///The socket connection was aborted.
            ///This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, 
            ///or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9950000'.

Comment: mhh ... i don't think your problem is located in the code you provided ... can you check if the other side is listening, reachable and responsive(in terms of deadlock or time consuming operation)?

Comment: yes, calling empty function, passing string and even List<TreeNode> work fine. Might error appear because this code is passing the message as whole, instead of streaming it?

Comment: can you post your binding config?

Comment: i think you could find this usefull ... http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/08/easing-the-pain-of-wcf-debugging/

Comment: >>> can you post your binding config? I don't think that I have any other then in the code above. It's net.tcp binding, that does not need that XML file, which would be need for an http binding.

Comment: i guess it will use the default settings without the config file ... somewhere in your code (receiver side of the failing call) you should have a NetTcpBinding object ... check that object for the values of the following properties: MaxReceivedMessageSize,MaxBufferSize,ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength and Security.Mode ...

Comment: yes, found it. I've edited it to the post above. I'll try adding the MaxReceivedMessageSize, etc. values to it.

Comment: what values should I assign to this properties?

Comment: YES! I've managed to transfer a tiny icon that way... therefor it should work in general, just need to play around with those settings!

Comment: that depends on your application, but you can read the current values ... compare the settings to the ammount of data in the bitmap byte-array ... maybe you would like to switch to jpeg or use some sort of compression